# Returning results from Vuex actions so that component can have access to it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm currently doing the Vuex Fundamentals course at Vue Mastery
The course notes say the following:
"We need a way for the component that ultimately triggered the error to gain access to that error. This means a couple things. First, we need to return the result of our Vuex actions’ API calls so that the component that dispatched them can receive that result. Second, we need the action that caught the error to throw it to the component that caused it, so it can catch it, too."

In the following link, you can see that the Vue Mastery instructor adds return statements to all the actions besides the one with the POST method. Can someone please explain to me why no return statement on the action with the POST method?
[Vue Mastery Lesson Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atPkq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Received this answer from the Vue forums:

The component who dispatched createEvent has to send the event as payload, so it already has access and that’s all the data you need.
The dispatch doesn’t return anything on itself.